# Visual studio use like VBA Editor

Tags: .net, scripting

I want implement in my software solution an VBA editor but in c# 3.0.

VBA edtior (vb 6.5) is obsolete. Microsoft have a solution for create macros and scripts editor for .net? if not how to implement a like solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for VSTA, [Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700828.aspx), which provides an IDE for .NET languages that can be integrated with your application similar to the VBA IDE.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700828.aspx

http://www.winwrap.com/web/basic/default.asp